# Vaadin : Filtering output on the table

Tags: java, search, filter, vaadin

im new in java component base framework, especially vaadin.
before use this framework, im using struts 2.

so when i want to query some table, i have a search box, contains many textfield. when user click Search Button, then the parameters from the texfield will be sent into my hibernate directly using http post.

my question, how to filter the output using vaadin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your BeanContainer with new data. Here is an example of my code

```
public void refreshTableData() {
    getBeanContainer().removeAllItems();
    List<Customer> customers = customerDao.getByCustomerFilter(getCustomerFilterForm().getFilterItem().getBean());
    getBeanContainer().addAll(customers);
}
```

Where *CustomerFilter* is a bean that has all the search criteria data, that I fill it within a form earlier (e.g with comboboxes), and beanContainer is my table container data source.

Comment: thanks for your answer J-unior. so i must to create container first?

Comment: Glad to help, I suggest you should read [this](https://vaadin.com/tutorial/-/chapter/databinding.binding.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
filterString = checkBox.getValue().toString();
Filterable f = (Filterable)(table.getContainerDataSource());
        if(filters==null)
            filters=new TreeMap<Object, SimpleStringFilter>();
        SimpleStringFilter filter=filters.remove(propertyId);
            if (filter != null){
                f.removeContainerFilter(filter);
            }
            filter = new SimpleStringFilter(propertyId, filterString, ignoreCase, onlyMatchPrefix);
        filters.put(propertyId, filter);
        f.addContainerFilter(filter);
```

Comment: You should Explain what your code is doing for the benefit of the asker.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to filter rows using a text that user inputs using textfield:

```
textField.addTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
                Filterable filter= (Filterable) (table.getContainerDataSource());
                filter.removeAllContainerFilters();

                String filterString = event.getText();
                if (filterString.length() > 0) {
                    filter.addContainerFilter(new Like("columnName", "%"+filterString +"%"));
                }

            }
        });
```

I hope code is selfexplanatory.